# Using nested Kivy parameters within a Widget's canvas

Tags: python, kivy, kivy-language

I'm making a Kivy layout using Kivy Language, and I've noticed that I can't seem to use nested parameters when defining the canvas of a Widget. This is what I mean:

**Example 1 - this runs fine**

```
<MainWidget>:

    Label:

        text: "Here is a button"
        var1: 1,0,0,1

        canvas.before:
            Color: 
                rgba: self.var1
            Rectangle:
                pos: self.pos
                size: self.size
```

**Example 2 - this failes with `TypeError: 'NoneType' object is not iterable`**

```
<MainWidget>:

    Label:

        text: "Here is a button"
        var1: 1,0,0,1
        var2: self.var1

        canvas.before:
            Color: 
                rgba: self.var2
            Rectangle:
                pos: self.pos
                size: self.size
```

*Python code for both*

```
from kivy.app import App
from kivy.uix.widget import Widget


class MainApp(App):

    def build(self):
        return MainWidget()


class MainWidget(Widget):
    pass


MainApp().run()
```

I think the problem here is that `var2` is None until `var1` is assigned, but this doesn't happen until after the object is initiated. Is there a way to do what I'm trying to do here?

**N.B.** This seems to only be a problem with the Widget's canvas. I can do e.g. this with no problems:

:

```
Label:

    text: "Here is a button"
    var1: 1,0,0,1
    var2: self.var1

    color: self.var2
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This happens for two reasons.
The `self` you are referring to, is referring to `Color`
If you give your label an id, then you can refer to its properties.
But in your case this would still not work, because the `var2` will only be set to `var1` after initiation of the object, so it is still `ObjectProperty(None)`. And it will be `None` untill the next frame.

You can make it work, if you define `var1` as a `ListProperty` in your class.

In py.

```
class MyLabel(Label):
    var2 = ListProperty([0,0,0,0])
```

Then in kv.

```
MyLabel:
    id: label
    text: "Here is a button"
    var1: 1,0,0,1
    var2: self.var1

    canvas.before:
        Color: 
            rgba: label.var2
        Rectangle:
            pos: label.pos
            size: label.size
```

Comment: Thanks, that's a good solution! Two things: a) I think your python code should be initialising var2, not var1 in the above example

Comment: and b) is there any way of doing this purely in kivy language?

Comment: @CharlieB, corrected, and I see you already wrote a purely kv example :)

Answer (score 1):

Thanks for @EL3PHANTEN for the tip: the following solution expands on his approach but doesn't require any modification to the Python or the creation of a custom class:

**Python code:** same as in the question

** Kivy Language**

```
<MainWidget>:

    Label:

        text: "Here is a button"
        var1: 1,1,0,1
        var2: self.var1

        canvas.before:
            Color:
                rgba: self.var2 if self.var2 is not None else [0,0,0,0]
            Rectangle: 
                pos: self.pos
                size: self.size
```

This works because all parameters defined by Kivy language seem to be set to None until they get a value.